Raydium Liquidity Pool V4: SwapBaseIn (Program Error: "insufficient funds")
I am creating a program in Java to send a swap transaction, but I keep receiving this error.
Transactions examples:
https://solscan.io/tx/46mZJDZFB9LeBnf8Vvq17JYemYPBBQhsqwZ68kmbGaTNGBbuppM6xmcYQFpBqMYSrr973xFyhYtEnNRQSGK3aQPC
https://solscan.io/tx/2PtGw2uDo59pwc8voHqsmBCDA2pQYtc1hBXivyKBAmeC8pGCmARN6jUWyGSUyBD7D5hkRzeJgHgzGAkG3wRcT3TT
Basically, what I am doing:

set ComputeUnitLimit
set ComputeUnitPrice
create WSol associated account
transfer amount to wsol associated account to pay for the swap and rent
create tokens associated account
Raydium swap
close Wsol associated account created in 3.

I am trying to swap 0.0001 SOL and the wallet has 0.038632336 SOL. The rent is 0.00203928.
Any help would be more than great!!
Thanks all!!


Without code we cant help. Maybe just add more SOL to wallet.

Please use text, rather than screenshots, to post your error.

Hi, did you ever solve this.  I am seeing the same things now. Thx.

Its probably because you miss the sync transaction that actually does the swap of sol to Wsol

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
